# Ribbon not initially rendered when using CSR in conjuction with React and TypeScript

Tags: list-view, ribbon, client-side-rendering, typescript, react

we have designed a few custom fields using CSR, TypeScript and React. On our AllItems.aspx, we use this to render a link for a "cross-site" lookup field which is really just a text field holding a lookup value. However, when we load our CSR script using JSLink, the ribbon doesn't get initially rendered. We have to click inside the List View WebPart for it to show up.

This is our script:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Label } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Label";

class ListViewCSR extends CsrBase {
    //...Fields

    constructor() {
        super();
        //...Constructor
    }

    protected getTemplates(): SPClientTemplates.TemplateOverrides {
        let templates: SPClientTemplates.TemplateOverrides = {};

        //...Templates

        return templates;
    }

    protected postRender(ctx: SPClientTemplates.RenderContext_FieldInForm) {
        //...PostRender fields
    } 
}

module ListViewModule {
    let form = new ListViewCSR();
    form.override();
    //Even when I comment this out, which will in turn cause the script to stop 
    //loading anything on the list view, the ribbon doesn't render initially.
}
```

As you can see in the comments, even when I comment out all code on our CSR script, the ribbon still won't load. So it can't be our code that's causing the problem. We load this script like so:

```
<JSLink>clienttemplates.js | ~Layouts/SP.CSR/Scripts/vendor.js?v=1.0.1.3 | ~Layouts/SP.CSR/Scripts/listview.js?v=1.0.1.3</JSLink>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some trial and error, I found the cause of the error. Apparently, JSLink tags need to have the Default="TRUE" attribute and be positioned right after the XslLink tag. (Not sure about the positioning above the XslLink tag, but the combination of the two solved my problem)